# Update global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a global variable in javascript like

```
var EventLocation = {

        'center' : '35.59214,-121.046048',
        'zoom' : 10
};
```

now in a function we update this variable as

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address =  $j('#EventLocation').text(); //record.Location;

 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

             EventLocation.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

             //onSuccessMaps(latitude,longitude);
        } else {
            alert('Fail to find location');
        }
    });
```

But in another function EventLocation.center is not updated, it take previous value as `('35.59214,-121.046048')`. 
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Where is EventLocation being defined? Inside a function or top level script file/tag?

Comment: have you tried to change the center attribute to a google maps latlng object from start?

Comment: try `window.EventLocation.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);`

Comment: EventLocation is defined in top of the javascript file, not in any function.

Comment: window.EventLocation.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); Its not working.

Comment: Andreas Lindgren, I am not getting what you want to try to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The geocode call is asynchronous, so the code will continue running while waiting for the response. You actually have to return the control to the browser before the response will be handled.

This means that any method that needs the coordinates has to be called from within the success callback method:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    EventLocation.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // here the coordinates _are_ set

    // this is where you put the code that needs to use the coordinates

  } else {
    alert('Fail to find location');
  }
});

// here the coordinates are _not_ set yet
```

Comment: @Ila: It's the same. Javascript is strictly single threaded, so only one method can run at a time. You have to exit out of all other methods before the success callback can run. Any code that needs the coordinates returned from the geocode call has to go inside the callback. I added some code above.

Comment: @Ila: There is nothing that would keep the value from being updated globally. You are just trying to use it before it's set.

Comment: @Ila: Yes, you are. It's the function that starts with `function(results, status) {`.

Comment: @Ila: I added a comment above in the code exactly where to put the code.

Comment: @Ila: Are you running all this in the `ready` event, so that the `#event_location_page` element exists?

Comment: @Ila: That is the HTML code, has it been parsed yet when you run the code, so that there is an element created from it?

Comment: I am not understanding your question.

Comment: If you put `alert($('#event_location_page').length);` in your code, does it show "0" or "1"?

Comment: @Ila: That's nice, it means that the element exists after all. If you alert something inside the pagecreate event handler, does it show up?

Comment: It will give every time EventLocation.center='center' : '35.59214,-121.046048'.

Comment: If you also alert the values right after changing them, which shows first?

Comment: What it means, I am not getting.

Comment: @Ila: In your code you are assigning a new value to `EventLocation.center`. If you put an alert right after that, does it show up before or after the alert inside the pagecreate event handler?

Comment: It will always gave me EventLocation.center='center' : '35.59214,-121.046048' this value with in page create.

Comment: @Ila: Read my previous comment again.

Comment: @Ila: In your previous comment you answered something completely different from what I asked.

Comment: I am not getting your previous  comment ": In your code you are assigning a new value to EventLocation.center. If you put an alert right after that, does it show up before or after the alert inside the pagecreate event handler? "

Comment: $('#map_canvas').gmap({
                 'center' : EventLocation.center,
                 'zoom' : EventLocation.zoom,
                 'disableDefaultUI' : true,
                 'zoomControl' : true,
                 'panControl': true,
                 'callback' : function() {
                     self.addMarker({
                         'position' :this.get('map').getCenter()
                     }).click(function() {  
                     });
                 }
             });
         }).load('event_location_page'); Here 'callback' function run only once.This is the problem

Comment: @Ila: `EventLocation.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); alert('Coordinates set.');`

Comment: @Ila: Does the newly added alert show up before or after the other alert?

Comment: yes alert is shown after and before page creation and it will give me different location everytime,but map is not refreshed and first loctaion shown every time means 'callback' : function() { self.addMarker({ 'position' :this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() { }); } }); }).load('event_location_page'); this code run only once.

Comment: @Ila: If the newly added alert shows up after the other, it means that you still do things in the wrong order. You should call the rest of the code from within the callback for `geocode`, otherwise it runs before the data is loaded.

Comment: @Ila: Why would it be called more than once?

Comment: @Ila: This is a different issue than what this question was about?

Comment: That was the part of this problem, I follow the step which you asking me to do, then there is no need to update global variable, but now callback function calls only once but I need to call that function everytime when I press the back button.

Comment: @Ila: There is far too little information in this question to answer that. You need to post information about what an "event" is, and how you navigate between them. Pressing the back button would normally go back to a previous page, and then you would load a new page when selecting an event. As you just expect the callback to be called again, that is clearly not what's happening in your application.